# click() method not trigger click event on anchor when dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created an anchor element using `document.createElement('a')` method but while trying to trigger click event then it does not fire click event.
For more detail refer following code

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", context+"/images/"+filePath);
link.setAttribute("href", "http://192.168.0.170:8082/abc/AttachmentData/getAttachment?path=pathTofile");
link.setAttribute("download", "abc.csv");
link.click();
```

I want to down load file .file link is provided in href.
This code is working on my local system but its not working when deployed on production server.

Comment: append the link in dom and call `link.click()`

Comment: does the console give any errors or warnings

Comment: The `href` `http://192.168.0.170:8082......` seems like a private IP, are you sure it's reachable url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just **created** the link element, but you have not **added** it to the document.

Try:

```
document.body.appendChild(link); // put it where you want the link show.
link.click()
```